# How to remove $0 invoices when listing all customer invoices

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe api to list all past invoices for a customer.  I'm developing in code igniter using the following library: https://github.com/bcessa/php-stripe/

```
$data['invoices'] = $this->stripe->invoice_list($customerId);
```

This works great however because I am using the trial_end feature when creating the customer stripe creates a $0 invoice, which then shows up in the customers invoice list.  What is the best way to handle this? I don't want that $0 invoice showing to the customer at all since it's really just a placeholder for the real upcoming charge.

Comment: without actually reading the API docs it's hard to tell if you can send a request that way,looks like you're going to have to either hack the library and loop through invoices and get rid of $0 invoices before returning them, or loop through and remove in your code before displaying invoices. Would you mind posting a sample of the returned data? ie whats in $data['invoices']

Comment: Just decided to go that way Bryan.  If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. Looped through and removed invoices that were $0. Doh..

Comment: Yeah Sorry there's not a cleaner way without doing some digging. WIll post as an answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without actually reading the API docs it's hard to tell if you can send a request that way,looks like you're going to have to either hack the library and loop through invoices and get rid of $0 invoices before returning them, or loop through and remove in your code before displaying invoices.

Comment: Just for documentation sake, I ended up looping through and checking to see if the $invoice->total === 0; Thanks Bryan

Comment: Yeah, sorry i couldn't help more. Glad you go it though.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate this is a very old question, but it came up on Google when I was looking for the answer. The easiest way seems to be to use the "Search invoices" API call

```php
$stripe->invoices->search([
  'query' => "customer:'{$customerId}' AND total>0",
]);
```

API References:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/search
- https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-invoices